# Flutter injectable is broken: Unhandled Exception: Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type ConcreteTest is not registered inside GetIt

Tags: flutter

I just discovered injectable. Love it, but I can't use environments. If I remove environments, everything works fine. I have tried to get it to work for the past 3 days but no luck. I believe the package breaks when newer Flutter and/or Dart. Or am I doing something wrong?

Creating a new Flutter project with the latest injectable and get_it versions results in the following error:

```bash
$ flutter run

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type ConcreteTest is not registered inside GetIt.
(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)
#0      throwIfNot (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:12:19)
#1      _GetItImplementation._findFactoryByNameAndType (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:396:5)
#2      _GetItImplementation.get (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:424:29)
#3      _GetItImplementation.call (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:464:12)
#4      main (package:injectable_environments/main.dart:9:8)
#5      _runMain.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:301:23)
#6      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
#7      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new Flutter project with `flutter create injectable_environments`
2. Add `flutter pub add injectable get_it`
3. Add `flutter pub add build_runner injectable_generator --dev`
4. Use the code below
5. Run `dart run build_runner watch` to create injectable.config.dart file
6. Finally, run `flutter run`

lib/main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:injectable_environments/concrete_test.dart';
import 'package:injectable_environments/injectable.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  configureDependencies();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // TRY THIS: Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see
        // the application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app,
        // try changing the seedColor in the colorScheme below to Colors.green
        // and then invoke "hot reload" (save your changes or press the "hot
        // reload" button in a Flutter-supported IDE, or press "r" if you used
        // the command line to start the app).
        //
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // state is not lost during the reload. To reset the state, use hot
        // restart instead.
        //
        // This works for code too, not just values: Most code changes can be
        // tested with just a hot reload.
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    getIt<ConcreteTest>();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // TRY THIS: Try changing the color here to a specific color (to
        // Colors.amber, perhaps?) and trigger a hot reload to see the AppBar
        // change color while the other colors stay the same.
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          //
          // TRY THIS: Invoke "debug painting" (choose the "Toggle Debug Paint"
          // action in the IDE, or press "p" in the console), to see the
          // wireframe for each widget.
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

lib/test.dart

```dart
abstract class ITest {
  void pass();
}
```

lib/concretetest.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:injectable_environments/test.dart';

@Injectable(as: ITest)
@Environment("dev") // or @dev
class ConcreteTest implements ITest {
  ConcreteTest();
  @override
  void pass() {
    debugPrint("passed");
  }
}
```

lib/injectable.dart

```dart
import 'package:injectable_environments/injectable.config.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';

final getIt = GetIt.instance;

//Define the Environments here
const dev = Environment('dev');
const prod = Environment('prod');

@InjectableInit(
  initializerName: r'$initGetIt', // default
  preferRelativeImports: true, // default
  asExtension: false, // default
)
void configureDependencies({Environment environment = dev}) {
  //we init the dependencies using a speciffic env
  $initGetIt(getIt, environment: environment.name);
}
```

Flutter environment:

```bash
Flutter 3.16.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7f20e5d18c (3 days ago) • 2023-11-27 09:47:30 -0800
Engine • revision 22b600f240
Tools • Dart 3.2.1 • DevTools 2.28.3
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two pits in your code.

The first one is that you're using the `as` tag, which means when you're calling `getIt<ConcreteTest>()`, it won't be able to find it, instead you need to do `getIt<ITest>`, because you bound the abstract class.

The second issue is, that whilst it looks like everything is working with your `Environment`, in your `configureDependencies` method, you forget to pass the environment down:

```
void configureDependencies({Environment environment = dev}) {
  $initGetIt(getIt, environment: environment.name); // pass environment.name here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 1. Doesn't add up since I have tried getIt<ITest>(). Also, this wouldn't make sense in a scenario where I have more than one concrete implementation of ITest. 2. I was passing the environment in my test project. I will update the question to reflect that.

Comment: I can only tell you what is wrong with the code you have shown us, and how to resolve the error you have also added in your post.

I wouldn't have posted the answer without having tested it first, if I can run it, and you can't, that suggests you have other issues, you need to clarify those.